# Log file for e-mail messages downloaded?

Tags: mail.app, logs

I have three IMAP mailboxes, and one Exchange mailbox.  Some recent software update deleted ALL of my rules and added one "News from Apple" but left that inactive.  So there are no automatic actions except for sending spam to the Junk folder.

Messages in Junk folder and messages I delete manually remain marked unread if I haven't actually "opened" them.

But almost every time I launch Mail, it says it is downloaded X new messages where X is usually more than one.  When that message goes away, there is rarely anything new in **any** folders, not even Inbox.

**Where (if anywhere) is a log file showing what Mail.app was trying to do for the first several seconds of launch?**

Comment: What exactly is the question here and how does the post relate to that?

Comment: The question is in the title AND in the bolded sentence which mysteriously disappeared but is now restored.

Comment: How does the part about the rules relate to the question about the Mail logs?

Comment: For the first several seconds of Mail running, it is performing authentication then synchronizing message headers  between the server and the the device and as it does so, processes the rules.  You are seeing that brief “new message” indicator because it likely was new but when synced by the server/client it changed status

Comment: "Rules" is pertinent because I had rules to delete certain messages (before Apple's strange decision and/or bug deleted them)

Comment: On launch, it says "connecting" for one to three seconds, and then usually "Downloading new messages" even though there typically are not any new messages.  A message that is not new and already read should not need to be downloaded and should not be called a new message.  Sometimes the "downloading" message is there for about ten seconds (5G cell modem→WiFi→MacBook)